# UNITY Application.OpenUrl() does not work on Android 7 Nougat

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm having this problem since running this app on Nougat

On this app, we have the option to download and open files from inside the app. On Android below 7, using Application.OpenUrl("path") was working very well, but when I was testing it on 7 (Samsung Galaxy Tab S2), suddenly it stopped working. On the documentation, it says that was blocked for security purposes. I tried using Application.OpenUrl and File.Open, but nothing works.

Is there an alternative to those functions? Or a way to force open files as before?

Comment: Could you share a link to "the documentation" and post what it says. Do you see an error in ADB logcat?

Comment: Perhaps you are faced with a similar problem, as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924520/how-to-open-a-pdf-in-an-android-unity3d-app).

Answer (score 0):

Define a public text asset.

```
public TextAsset textFile;
```

And then, in start:

```
void Start ()
{
    textFile = (TextAsset)Resources.Load ("putFileNameHere", typeof(TextAsset));
    string fileContent = textFile.text;
}
```